# How to split/divide Structure into two parts in CF?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

I have a **Structure** which gives me more than 100 scopes. I want to **split** those scopes into two parts, so that i can run those scopes in two different intervals by passing a url variable.

```
<cfdump var="#variables[dynVarName]#">  ---- Struct of scopes

<cfset howManyCustomScopes = listLen(structkeylist(variables[dynVarName],"|" ),"|" )>
<!--- looping over collection of scopes ---->
<cfloop collection="#variables[dynVarName]#" item="t">              
            <cfset tempurl = variables[dynVarName][t]["url"]>
            <cfset tempurl = tempurl & "&retainCache=1">            
            <cfoutput>
                <cfhttp url="#tempurl#" method="GET" resolveurl="false" timeout="4000">
                #tempurl#<br>
                <cfset scopesCachedCounter = scopesCachedCounter + 1>
                <cfmodule template="#Request.Library.CustomTags.VirtualPath#Scheduler_LogDetail.cfm" Step="Funded Scopes Cache" Detail="#scopesCachedCounter#.- #t#" LogData="#tempurl#"></cfmodule>
            </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

So i want to split those scopes into two parts. Any idea how to do it in CF?
the dump of :  gives me something like :
[image]

Comment: Can you confirm something, your image is showing a structure not an array, so are you attempting to split up this structure or some other array?

Comment: you are correct. i am attempting to split this structure given in the screen shot. "#variables[dynVarName]#"

Comment: If you're actually working with structs not an arrays, you should update your question to reflect that. They're two different things. If it is a struct, what defines where one "part" finishes, and the next "part" starts? Structs have no sense of order in their keys, whereas the notion of a *first* part and a *second* part do. Is it a case that if the stuct has ten keys, you want any five of them in each of two parts?

Comment: @AdamCameron is correct. Structures have no sense of order, but I guess if you just want to split it down the middle, you can use StructCount to get the total number of keys and then do a loop over the structure using the "collection" attribute and do something within that loop to separate the first X keys into one new structure and the second X keys into another structure.

Comment: @Adam- Yeah exactly, i want to divide the keys into two parts. If this structure has 100 records, i want 50-50 of them.

Comment: @andrewdixon: ok, i am not concerned about the orders. i just want to split this structure. I will try StructCount. will update you asap. thanks

Comment: So basically what i did is counts the number of keys. 
<cfset howManyCustomScopes = listLen(structkeylist(variables[dynVarName],"|" ),"|" )>..... which gives me count of 139.

Comment: Why didn't you just do what Andrew suggested & use structCount()? And can you pls revise your question/title to stop asking about arrays.

Comment: So you can now divide this number by two and use cfloop collection to loop over the structure and divide it into two new structures.

Comment: OK. question updated.. i did the StructCount. <cfset countStruct = StructCount(variables[dynVarName])>
 <cfdump var="#countStruct#">, gives me the same number 139. Divided the count like howManyCustomScopes/2. But if the struct count is odd number then what?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the use case for this. If you do not care about the orders, how will you know which elements are in each 'part' based on the URL variables you spoke of? I see Adam has answered the question..and it was accepted. Now that you have the 'how', can you share the 'why'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, we've got enough to go on now.

This demonstrates a potential solution:

```
source = {
    key1 = "value1",
    key2 = "value2",
    key3 = "value3",
    key4 = "value4",
    key5 = "value5"
};
splitAt = structCount(source) \ 2;

first = {};
second = {};
structToPopulate = first;

for (key in source){
    structToPopulate[key] = source[key];
    if (structCount(structToPopulate) > splitAt){
        structToPopulate = second;
    }
}
writeDump([source,first,second]);
```